# How to match specific list sequence against dictreader row?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have the following lists:

main_list:

```
[4, 1, 5]
```

iterated lists/two rows from dict:

```
['John', '1', '4', '3']
['Mary', '4', '1', '5']
```

the iterated list is from the below, dictionary being csv.DictReader(x):

```
for row in dictionary:
    print(list(row.values()))
```

I want the below to work, where if my main_list matches a sequence from the dictionary list, it will spit out the first column, in which the header is 'name':

```
if main_list in list(row.values()):
    print(row['name'])
```

For the example above, as Mary's items match 4, 1, 5, the final returned value should be Mary.

I'm new to Python, and I would appreciate any advice on how to work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extended tuple unpacking to split a row into its *name* and the rest.

```
name,*therest = `['Mary', '4', '1', '5']
```

Then make the comparison

```
test = [4, 1, 5]
if therest == [str(thing) for thing in test]:
    print(name)
```